# ubuntu 14.04 public key authentication not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, public-key-encryption

I am running an ubuntu 14.04 vm in VirtualBox.

I am trying to set up public key authentication.

I get the following debug info with the -vvv parameter:

```
hduser@peter-VirtualBox:/var/log$ ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

I searched some forums and found one suggestion that i confirm that my home directory, ~/.ssh and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys files are ONLY writable by myself, which is true.

anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently sshd is not listening on port 22. Have you installed the server? Is the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` correct? Also look for logged errors in `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: you were right. i googled and installed sshd using info on this page: 

[ubuntu sshd install page](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html).

thanks!

can you post this as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the SSH Server `sshd` is not listening on port 22. Have you installed it yet? (A guide to do so, suggested by Peter: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html)

An other reason that `sshd` does not start might be a faulty configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Error messages for that should appear in the `/var/log/auth.log` log file. Alternatively you can try to run `sudo service ssh start`. Error messages should then also be printed in the current window.

Finally, `sshd` might be listening on a non-default port. Usually you would be aware of that, though, as it requires manual changes to the configuration. You can get an overview of all open ports by calling `sudo netstat -tulpen`. In the defaul case you'll have a line with `sshd` in the `Program name` column and `0.0.0.0:22` in the `LocalAddress` column. This means that sshd is listening on all ipv4 interfaces available (`0.0.0.0`) on port 22 (`:22`). If you find a different port there (e.g. 12345), you can tell ssh to connect to it instead using the `-p` flag (`ssh localhost -p 12345`).